# What is the difference between Jet Wash and Jet Blast?

Tags: jet-engine, wake-turbulence, turbulence

I was reading about [Wake Turbulence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_turbulence) in Wikipedia and got to know about Jet Wash and Wing Vortex. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_blast), Jet Blast is the movement of air from the jet exhaust. Isn't this same as Jet Wash? What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Jet Blast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_blast) is the force or wind generated behind a jet engine, particularly on or before takeoff when high/full power is set, but also when the aircraft is taxiing.

[image: Jet Blast]

When an object moves through air (or some other medium, e.g. a spoon through nutella), air is disturbed. This disturbance or [wake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake) is known as [wake turbulence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_turbulence). It can also be called [jet wash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_wash).

The difference is that jet blast is only because of engines. Jet wash or prop wash or wake turbulence is because the airplane moves through air.

If Mr Kevin Fast runs at say 100 mph doing this (see picture below), you can notice significant wake turbulence, although the engines are off and there is no jet blast.

[image: Kevin Fast]

Comment: I can confirm that jet blast makes it difficult to stand, and also blows laptops away if you don't catch them. :)